# How to apply XPATH on multiple files in eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xpath, eclipse-plugin

I have like 20 html files in a tree structure in my eclipse project.
Now I want to delete all <div class="a" /> from them.
If it were spanning single line I would write regexp to do that, but content of this div is allways different.

So I think doing the same with XPath would do the trick, but I can't find any plugin that allow me to do that.

How would you do that?

Comment: can you post a html file as an example ? Point out the div you want to remove.

Comment: Are you asking for an XPath expression to select such elements? Are you asking for an XPath implementation? Are you asking for an eclipse-plugin doing all this for you?

Comment: @Alejandro mainly XPath plugin

Answer (score 1):

I find that ant provides a convenient wrapper for xslt. You could create an ant build file and use the [xslt task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html) to do your transformation for a batch of files.

Eclipse provides a nice interface for executing ant targets. Simple way to implement your own "plugin".